# Refresh view to apply newly selected theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have added a `dropdownlist` in my application which populates list of all themes available. I added this dropdown in my _Layout.cshtml page.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div style="float: right;" class="themeSelector" id="themeSelector">
        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px;">
            Theme:
        </div>
        @Html.DropDownList("themeComboBox", IMCC_PAS.Controllers.AvailableThemes.Themes, new { autopostback = "true", @style = "height:20px; width: 80px;margin-left:5px; margin-top: 8px;" })
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

on respective views, I read the current theme using jquery

```
var theme = $("#themeComboBox").val();
```

and apply the theme on my controls as required.

But how do I refresh my controls when a theme is changed?

this is how theme is being applied to the controls on pages.

```
$("fabGrid").jqxGrid({ theme: 'nameOfTheme' });
$("chkAllBtn").jqxButton({ theme: 'nameOfTheme' });
```

and when theme is changed, it should reflect on all pages (each page will have grids, buttons etc.)

P.S: theme is applied on different controls (grid, dropdownlists, buttons etc.) and may or may not be in `submit form`.

Comment: You need to remove the current theme's `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/...">` and append a new stylesheet `<link>` to `head` based on `var theme`. How are these `theme` css file named? What does `IMCC_PAS.Controllers.AvailableThemes.Themes` return?

Comment: `AvailableThemes` return a `SelectList` of themes (string names of themes like `dark`, `light` etc. theme files are named like `dark.css` and are bundled in the _layout page.

Answer (score 1):

In your `_Layout`, load a default theme like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/themes/light.css" id="theme-stylesheet" />
```

And then in your js:

```
$("#themeComboBox").change(function(){
    $("#theme-stylesheet").attr("href", "/content/themes/" + $(this).val() + ".css");
});
```

Now, based the dropdown value, different `css` files are loaded.

**Update** after changes to the question:

If you want to change jqGrid's themes, it will be similar:

```
$("#themeComboBox").change(function(){
    $("#theme-stylesheet").attr("href", "/content/jqwidgets/styles/" + $(this).val() + ".css");
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/6bbbubpk/1/).

The relative path will change according to your setup. Also, make sure the values in the options matches with the `css` file name.

Comment: this was good to know but can you please see the edited question? Im sorry I should have mentioned that in the first place.

Comment: @WAQ I'm not familiar with jqGrid. But looking at their documentation, you'd have to do something similar. You need to change the `energyblue` part with whatever is selected in the dropdown. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" type="text/css" />`

Comment: @WAQ Updated the answer.

Comment: no. it does not work like this in jqxWidget controls. you specify the theme for each control using `theme` property of each control like i mentioned in my question's edited part.